# replace double quoted hash with sed

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem replacing default password hash in config file:

```
sed -i 's/default_password_crypted: "[^"]*"/default_password_crypted: "\$1\$mF86/UHC\$WvcIcXred6crBz2onWxyac."/' input.txt
```

i get following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 74: unknown option to `s'

works:

```
search pattern: default_password_crypted: "$1$mF86/UHC$WvcIcX2t6crBz2onWxyac."

sed -i 's/default_password_crypted: "[^"]*"/default_password_crypted: "1234567890"/' input.txt
```

how do i need to write replace pattern for hash ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the literal `/` inside your replacement as it’s the delimiter:

```
sed -i 's/default_password_crypted: "[^"]*"/default_password_crypted: "\$1\$mF86\/UHC\$WvcIcXred6crBz2onWxyac."/' input.txt
```

Or simply use a different character, for example a `,`:

```
sed -i 's,default_password_crypted: "[^"]*",default_password_crypted: "\$1\$mF86,UHC\$WvcIcXred6crBz2onWxyac.",' input.txt
```

You also don’t need to escape the `$` inside the replacement.

Comment: thx m8 1st works perfectly , i´ll never get arround regex , grrrr but changing $mF86, <-- will change the hash ?!

Comment: this is original password hash string "$1$mF86/UHC$WvcIcX2t6crBz2onWxyac." if i replace the "/" after "$1$mmF86.." with "," hash is changed

Comment: @manga I meant you should use a different delimiter instead of `/` if you don’t want to escape it inside pattern/replacement.